Complex Value of a Volume via a Triple Integral
To find the volume of a sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin using Cartesian coordinates, we consider the triple integral:
$$\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\int_{-R}^R\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz=\frac43\pi R^3\tag{1}$$
As an alternative method, I thought of considering:
$$\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}\int_{-R}^R\int_{-R}^R\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz\tag{2}$$
since this represents the volume of the intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ with the infinite parallelopiped $-R\le x,y\le R$.
My approach:
$$\mathcal I=\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}\int_{-R}^R\int_{-R}^R\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$$
$$=8\int_0^R\int_0^R\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$
$$=4\int_0^R\left[x\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}+(R^2-y^2)\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}\right)\right]_0^R\mathrm dy$$
$$=4\int_0^RR\sqrt{-y^2}+(R^2-y^2)\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}\right)\mathrm dy$$
$\because \text{The principal value of }\sin^{-1}x=\frac{\pi}2+i\cosh^{-1}x\forall x>1 $
$$\implies \mathcal I=4\int_0^RiRy+(R^2-y^2)\left(\frac{\pi}2+i\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}\right)\right)\mathrm dy$$
$$\implies \mathcal I=4\int_0^RiRy+(R^2-y^2)\left(\frac{\pi}2+i\tanh^{-1}\frac{y}{R}\right)\mathrm dy$$
$$\implies \mathcal I=\left[2iRy^2+2\pi R^2y-\frac23\pi y^3\right]_0^R+4i\int_0^R(R^2-y^2)\tanh^{-1}\frac{y}{R}\mathrm dy$$
$$\implies \mathcal I=\frac43\pi R^3+2iR^3+4iR^3\int_0^1(1-t^2)\tanh^{-1}t\mathrm dt$$
where $y=tR$. Let:
$$\mathcal I_1=\int_0^1(1-t^2)\tanh^{-1}t\mathrm dt$$
$$=\left[t\tanh^{-1}t\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{t}{1-t^2}\mathrm dt-\left[\frac13t^3\tanh^{-1}t\right]_0^1+\frac13\int_0^1\frac{(-t)(1-t^2)+t}{1-t^2}\mathrm dt$$
$$=\left[\left(t-\frac{t^3}3\right)\tanh^{-1}t+\frac13\ln(1-t^2)-\frac{t^2}6\right]_0^1$$
$$=\lim_{t\to1}\left(t-\frac{t^3}3\right)\tanh^{-1}t+\frac13\ln(1-t^2)-\frac{t^2}6$$
$$=-\frac16+\frac16\lim_{t\to1}(-t^3+3t+2)\ln(1+t)+(t^3-3t+2)\ln(1-t)$$
$$=\frac{2\ln2}3-\frac16+\frac12\lim_{t\to1}(1-t)^2\ln(1-t)$$
$\because \lim_{x\to0}x\ln x=0$
$$\implies \mathcal I_1=\frac{2\ln2}3-\frac16$$
$$\implies \mathcal I=\frac43\pi R^3+2iR^3+4iR^3\left(\frac{2\ln2}3-\frac16\right)$$
$$\therefore \mathcal I=\frac43\pi R^3+\frac23iR^3\ln\left(16e^2\right)$$
Query : Why am I getting an imaginary part also?
I have checked my answer many times, but am not able to find any mistake. Can someone kindly point it/them out?

I think the third equality is wrong, there should not be a $-x^2$ in the denominator.

Sorry, I accidentally typed it. Thanks!

I think the problem stems from the fact that your integral bounds are undefined in the real space. At the extreme values of $x$ and $y$, which are both $\pm R$, the boundary values for $z$ are complex: $\pm\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}|_{x,y=\pm R} = \pm\sqrt{R^2-2R^2} = \pm iR$.

@EgorLarionov I observed that but why does that happen? Geometrically, as I have mentioned in the question, the integral should represent the volume of a sphere.

@RakshithPL, that's the point! It doesn't! The span of $x$ and $y$ yield a square, which you try to move along the $z$-direction to form a sphere, but it can't be a sphere, because the initial object is not a circle, but a square.

@EgorLarionov I am saying that the conditions on $x$ and $y$ yield an infinite rectangular prism-shaped region, and the condition on $z$ yields a sphere, which on intersection with the $1^{st}$ region still yields the same sphere.

You haven't specified the intersection in your integral, mate. For instance, given a sphere of radius $R=1$, the intersection (as you claim) shouldn't contain the point $P=(1, 1,  R^2-2)$ as it should lie on a sphere. However, your integral contains that point.

@EgorLarionov no, according to me, those points inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ are only considered in my integral. Although the region traced out by $x$ and $y$ is an infinite rectangular prism, the boundary conditions on $z$ imply the complete region spanned by $x$, $y$ and $z$ is the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$. Kindly point out if I am wrong somewhere, as I have just started learning about triple integrals.

@RakshithPL Yes, you are. The boundaries of the integral should run along all the possible points within the volume of an object you're integrating over. The equation of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ gives specific constraints on possible values of $x, y, z$. Your integral boundaries do not yield the same constraints. Moreover, the very intersection of the sphere with the prism you mentioned gives the same sphere! That means that your integral (in terms of the boundaries) can't possibly change because you haven't changed the shape.

@EgorLarionov thanks, I got where I went wrong.

@RakshithPL, happy to assist, mate!

There are too many things wrong here , at the Initial Stages.
(I) Whether it is either of these , it is fundamentally flawed.
$$\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}\int_{-R}^R\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz=\frac43\pi R^3\tag{1.1}$$
$$\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\int_{-R}^R\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz=\frac43\pi R^3\tag{1.2}$$
Here , we have $dxdydz$ , hence we have to integrate the inner integral by $x$ first time , then we put in the limits for $x$ , then $x$ variable is no longer available in the terms for the next 2 integrations.
Hence we can not have the next limit containing $x$ , though it might contain $y$ & $z$.
When we integrate the second time , we have to use $y$ , then put in the limits for $y$ , then variable $y$ is no longer available in the terms for the last integration.
When we integrate the third time , we have to use $z$ , then put in the limits for $z$ , then we can not use limits in terms of $x$ , $y$ which are no longer available.
(II) Same Issue is there in (2) , where the last outer integral can not have limits in terms of $x$ , $y$ : it is fundamentally flawed.
(III) More-over , we can think of the intersection between Sphere & Parallelopiped , though we have to use the right limits , we can not use the limits for Parallelopiped ( which is larger ) , we have to use the limits for Sphere ( which is smaller )
(IV) Continuing that , when we integrate outside the relevant volume , we might get negative volume element or even imaginary volume element like here.
Eventually , adding those up will give Complex Volume.
Eg : let us calculate the Area of the Curve $x=y^2$ [[ $y=\sqrt{x}$ ]] till $x=1$ : We can integrate $\sqrt{x}$ starting at $x=0$ : $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}dy$

We can say that the Area is the intersection between right half & the given Curve , hence we can integrate over larger limits. That is a wrong assumption :
When we wrongly take limits $x=-1$ to $x=+1$ , like $\int_{-1}^{+1}\sqrt{x}dy$ , we will be adding up Imaginary Area $\sqrt{-1}$ to get Complex Area.
In OP Case , we can easily see that occurring , when we use the given limits to get $\pm\sqrt{R^2-R^2-R^2}$ , which is Imaginary.
(V) Lastly , when we use $\sin^{-1}x=\frac{\pi}2+i\cosh^{-1}x$ , we are automatically introducing Imaginary numbers ourselves !
Naturally , Volume will turn out Complex , though that is wrong.
SUGGESTIONS : use the right order for the integrations , then use the right limits using the right terms in the right variables. Things will automatically work out !
ADDENDUM :
OP has/had some confusion over order of Integration , where this might assist a little :
Order is wrong :
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{2}^{3}\int_{4}^{5} A dxdydz \not \equiv \{ \int_{x=0}^{x=1} [ \int_{y=2}^{y=3} ( \int_{z=4}^{z=5} A dx ) dy ] dz \} $$
Order is right :
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{2}^{3}\int_{4}^{5} A dxdydz \equiv \{ \int_{z=0}^{z=1} [ \int_{y=2}^{y=3} ( \int_{x=4}^{x=5} A dx ) dy ] dz \} $$
It is "Palindrome Way" , like nesting Parenthesis.
Here the outer integral limits for $z$ must be Constants , not involving $x$ , $y$ there.
Coming to the inner integral limits for $x$ , we might have Constants , we might involve $y$ , $z$ , we can not involve $x$ there.
When we change the order , we must handle the limits too.

Thanks for the answer, I agree with points (III), (IV), (V) and the example you provided and understood where I went wrong. But I disagree with (I) and (II) because when we integrate over general regions with boundaries of $y$ as a function of $x$ and boundaries of $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, we first integrate w.r.t. $z$, then $y$ and then $x$.

In that Case , you have to write & use $dzdydx$ , to match the order.

But the order can be interchanged as per convenience by Fubini's theorem. Also, in the integral $(1)$, the order and the limits match, plus the constraints on $x$, $y$ and $z$ exactly trace out the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$, so I don't see any problem with it.

The order is generally written in "Palindrome Way" : $\int_1\int_2\int_3dzdydx$ indicates integrating inner most by $z$ , then integrating by $y$ , while integrating outer most by $x$. We can change the order , though we have to change the limits accordingly , while updating $dxdydz$ order too.

Yes, I agree with you. But when the integration bounds for $y$ and/or $z$ depend on $x$, first $y$ and/or $z$ has/have to be integrated first so that we can obtain a function in $x$. I don't understand why you have mentioned the opposite in your answer.

I mentioned the opposite because I copy-pasted what you used : $dxdydz$ : then the inner most integral is $dx$ with the given limits from $-R$ to $+R$. That is why I said it is fundamentally wrong !

Ok, I understood my mistake. Thanks for the patience.

No worries , I have added a new content , that might assist in resolving the confusion.

I wanted to ask: Can we say that when the bounds are larger than the constraints involved, that is, they result in imaginary parts too, is the real part obtained always the volume of the smaller region?

That may occur when the "Extra Part/Volume/Area" contributes Imaginary numbers only. There are Scenarios where the "Extra Part/Volume/Area" contributes Complex numbers or real numbers , which will make the over-all value not match at all. Eg1 when integrating over Cone , we might take "Extra Volume" which makes it a Sphere. Eg2 when integrating over Circle , we might take "Extra Area" which makes it a Square. More-over , we were integrating the Constant function $1$ here , though when we use some other function , there is more weirdness. Over-all it is highly arbitrary , which we should avoid.

So does that mean we cannot predict whether or not we will get a real part if shape does not change? Like if I integrate $\ln x$ from $-e^2$ to $-1$, I am getting $e^2+1$ as the real part.

Yes , we can not predict in general.
